# Forward List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written Forward List in c++ for learning purpose. There are a few things to be added yet, but do you have any thoughts on the code as for now?

ForwardList.h

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

namespace PrimLibrary
{
    // base node - used as before head node
    template <class T>
    struct ForwardList_NodeBase
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase* next;

        ForwardList_NodeBase(ForwardList_NodeBase* _next = nullptr) :
            next{ _next }
        {

        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct ForwardList_Node : public ForwardList_NodeBase<T>
    {
        T data;

        ForwardList_Node(const T& _data, ForwardList_Node* _next = nullptr) :
            ForwardList_NodeBase{ _next },
            data{ _data }
        {

        }
    };

    template <class T, class UnqualifiedType = std::remove_cv_t<T>>
    class ForwardListIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, UnqualifiedType, std::ptrdiff_t, T*, T&>
    {
    public:

        explicit ForwardListIterator(ForwardList_NodeBase<UnqualifiedType>* node) :
            _itr{ node }
        {

        }

        ForwardListIterator(const ForwardListIterator&) = default;
        ForwardListIterator(const ForwardListIterator&& rhs) noexcept :
        _itr{ rhs._itr }
        {
            rhs._itr = nullptr;
        }

        ForwardListIterator& operator=(const ForwardListIterator& rhs)
        {
            _itr = rhs._itr;
            return *this;
        }

        ForwardListIterator& operator=(const ForwardListIterator&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            std::swap(_itr, rhs._itr);
            return *this;
        }


        ForwardListIterator& operator++()
        {
            assert(_itr != nullptr && "Iterator out-of-bounds.");
            _itr = static_cast<ForwardList_Node<UnqualifiedType>*>(_itr)->next;
            return *this;
        }

        ForwardListIterator& operator++(int)
        {
            assert(_itr != nullptr && "Iterator out-of-bounds.");
            auto tmp(*this);
            _itr = static_cast<ForwardList_Node<UnqualifiedType>*>(_itr)->next;
            return *this;
        }

        T& operator*() const
        {
            assert(_itr != nullptr && "Iterator out-of-bounds.");
            return static_cast<ForwardList_Node<UnqualifiedType>*>(_itr)->data;
        }

        T& operator->() const
        {
            assert(_itr != nullptr && "Iterator out-of-bounds.");
            return static_cast<ForwardList_Node<UnqualifiedType>*>(_itr)->data;
        }

        bool operator==(const ForwardListIterator& rhs) const
        {
            return _itr == rhs._itr;
        }

        bool operator!=(const ForwardListIterator& rhs) const
        {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }

        ForwardList_NodeBase<UnqualifiedType>* getNode() const
        {
            return _itr;
        }


    private:
        ForwardList_NodeBase<UnqualifiedType>* _itr;
    };

    template <class T>
    class ForwardList
    {

    public:

        using iterator = ForwardListIterator<T>;
        using const_iterator = ForwardListIterator<const T>;

        ForwardList();
        ~ForwardList();

        ForwardList(std::initializer_list<T> il);

        template<class InputIterator>
        ForwardList(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);

        ForwardList(const ForwardList& rhs);
        ForwardList(ForwardList&& rhs) noexcept;

        ForwardList& operator=(const ForwardList& rhs);
        ForwardList& operator=(ForwardList&& rhs) noexcept;


        // TODO: operator override;
        // TODO: additional modifiers

        T& front() { assert(_beforeBegin.next != nullptr && "No data to get - empty list"); return static_cast<ForwardList_Node<T>*>(_beforeBegin.next)->data; }
        const T& front() const { assert(_beforeBegin.next != nullptr && "No data to get - empty list");  return static_cast<ForwardList_Node<T>*>(_beforeBegin.next)->data; }

        // Iterators
        iterator begin() { return iterator{ _beforeBegin.next }; }
        iterator end() { return iterator{ nullptr }; }

        const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator{ _beforeBegin.next }; }
        const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator{ nullptr }; }

        const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
        const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }

        iterator before_begin() { return iterator{ &_beforeBegin }; }
        const_iterator before_begin() const { return const_iterator{ &_beforeBegin }; }
        const_iterator cbefore_begin() const { return before_begin(); }

        bool empty() const noexcept { return _beforeBegin.next == nullptr; }

        // Modifiers
        void push_front(const T& value);
        void push_front(std::initializer_list<T> il);

        void push_back(const T& value);
        void push_back(std::initializer_list<T> il);

        void push_after(const T& value, iterator itr);
        void push_after(std::initializer_list<T> il, iterator itr);

        template <class InputIterator>
        void push_after(iterator itr, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);

        void pop_front();

        void remove(const T& value);

        template<class Comparator>
        void remove_if(Comparator cmp);

        void erase_after(iterator itr); // (itr, itr+1]
        void erase_after(iterator begin, iterator end); // (begin, end)
        void clear();

        void swap(ForwardList& other);

        void splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList& other);
        void splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList& other, iterator otherIt);
        void splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList& other, iterator otherBegin, iterator otherEnd);

    private:
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T> _beforeBegin;
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* _back; // for quick pushback
    };

    template<class T>
    bool operator==(const ForwardList<T>& lhs, const ForwardList<T>& rhs)
    {
        auto lhsIt = lhs.begin();
        auto rhsIt = rhs.begin();

        const auto lhsEnd = lhs.end();
        const auto rhsEnd = rhs.end();

        for (;lhsIt != lhsEnd && rhsIt != rhsEnd; ++lhsIt, ++rhsIt)
        {
            if (*lhsIt != *rhsIt)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // lists have different sizes
        if (lhsIt != lhsEnd || rhsIt != rhsEnd)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    template<class T>
    bool operator!=(const ForwardList<T>& lhs, const ForwardList<T>& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```

ForwardList.cpp

```
#include "ForwardList.h"

namespace PrimLibrary
{
    template <class T>
    ForwardList<T>::ForwardList() :
        _back{ nullptr }
    {

    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>::~ForwardList()
    {
        clear();
    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>::ForwardList(std::initializer_list<T> il) :
        _back{ nullptr }
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = &_beforeBegin;

        for (const T& value : il)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;
        }

        _back = lastNewNode;
    }

    template<class T>
    template<class InputIterator>
    ForwardList<T>::ForwardList(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) :
        _back{ nullptr }
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = &_beforeBegin;

        while (begin != end)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ *begin };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;

            ++begin;
        }

        _back = lastNewNode;
    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>::ForwardList(const ForwardList& rhs) :
        _back{ nullptr }
    {
        for (const T& nodeData : rhs)
        {
            push_back(nodeData);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>::ForwardList(ForwardList &&rhs) noexcept :
        _back{ nullptr }
    {
        std::swap(_beforeBegin, rhs._beforeBegin);
        std::swap(_back, rhs._back);
    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>& ForwardList<T>::operator=(const ForwardList & rhs)
    {
        ForwardList safeCopy{ rhs };
        std::swap(*this, safeCopy);
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    ForwardList<T>& ForwardList<T>::operator=(ForwardList && rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(_beforeBegin, rhs._beforeBegin);
        std::swap(_back, rhs._back);
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_front(const T& value)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newFront = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value };
        if (_beforeBegin.next == nullptr)
        {
            _beforeBegin.next = _back = newFront;
        }
        else
        {
            newFront->next = _beforeBegin.next;
            _beforeBegin.next = newFront;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_front(std::initializer_list<T> il)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = _beforeBegin.next;
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = &_beforeBegin;

        for (const T& value : il)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;
        }

        if (firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = lastNewNode;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNewNode->next = firstAfterPush;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_back(const T& value)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newBack = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value,  nullptr };

        if (_beforeBegin.next == nullptr)
        {
            _beforeBegin.next = _back = newBack;
        }
        else
        {
            _back->next = newBack;
            _back = newBack;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_back(std::initializer_list<T> il)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = _back ? _back : &_beforeBegin;

        for (const T& value : il)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;
        }

        _back = lastNewNode;
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_after(const T& value, iterator itr)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newBack = new ForwardList_Node<T>(value);
        newBack->next = itr.getNode()->next;
        itr.getNode()->next = newBack;
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_after(std::initializer_list<T> il, iterator itr)
    {
        assert(itr.getNode() != nullptr && "Iterator out of bounds");

        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = itr.getNode()->next;
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = itr.getNode();

        for (const T& value : il)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ value };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;
        }

        if (firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = firstAfterPush;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNewNode->next = firstAfterPush;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    template<class InputIterator>
    void ForwardList<T>::push_after(iterator itr, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = itr.getNode()->next;
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* lastNewNode = itr.getNode();

        while (begin != end)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* newNode = new ForwardList_Node<T>{ *begin };
            lastNewNode->next = newNode;
            lastNewNode = newNode;
            ++begin;
        }

        if (firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = firstAfterPush;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNewNode->next = firstAfterPush;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::pop_front()
    {
        if (_beforeBegin.next)
        {
            ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* oldFront = _beforeBegin.next;
            _beforeBegin.next = oldFront->next;
            delete oldFront;

            // do i need this? we wont be accessing back when front is nullptr
            if (_beforeBegin.next == nullptr)
            {
                _back = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::remove(const T& value)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* previous = &_beforeBegin;
        while (previous->next != nullptr)
        {
            ForwardList_Node<T>* current = static_cast<ForwardList_Node<T>*>(previous->next);
            if (current->data == value)
            {
                previous->next = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = current;
            }
        } 

        // in case last element was removed
        _back = previous;
    }


    template<class T>
    template<class Comparator>
    void ForwardList<T>::remove_if(Comparator cmp)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* previous = &_beforeBegin;
        while (previous->next != nullptr)
        {
            ForwardList_Node<T>* current = static_cast<ForwardList_Node<T>*>(previous->next);
            if (cmp(current->data))
            {
                previous->next = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = current;
            }
        }

        // in case last element was removed
        _back = previous;
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::erase_after(iterator itr)
    {
        assert(itr.getNode()->next != nullptr);
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* toPop = itr.getNode()->next;
        itr.getNode()->next = toPop->next;
        delete toPop;

        if (itr.getNode()->next == nullptr)
        {
            _back = itr.getNode();
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::erase_after(iterator begin, iterator end)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* current = begin.getNode()->next;
        while (current != end.getNode())
        {
            auto tmp = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = tmp;
        }

        begin.getNode()->next = end.getNode();
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::clear()
    {
        while (!empty())
        {
            pop_front();
        }
    }
    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::swap(ForwardList &other)
    {
        std::swap(_beforeBegin.next, other._beforeBegin.next);
        std::swap(_back, other._back);
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList& other)
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = position.getNode()->next;

        position.getNode()->next = other._beforeBegin.next;
        other._back->next = firstAfterPush;

        if (firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = other._back;
        }

        other._beforeBegin.next = other._back = nullptr;
    }

    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList & other, iterator otherIt) // range (otherIt, ++otherIt]
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = position.getNode()->next;
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* nodeToMove = otherIt.getNode()->next;

        otherIt.getNode()->next = nodeToMove->next;

        position.getNode()->next = nodeToMove;
        nodeToMove->next = firstAfterPush;

        if (firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = nodeToMove;
        }
    }
    template<class T>
    void ForwardList<T>::splice_after(iterator position, ForwardList & other, iterator otherBegin, iterator otherEnd) // (otherBegin, otherLast) range
    {
        ForwardList_NodeBase<T>* firstAfterPush = position.getNode()->next;

        position.getNode()->next = otherBegin.getNode()->next;

        iterator lastNodeToMove{ otherBegin };
        while (lastNodeToMove.getNode()->next != otherEnd.getNode())
        {
            ++lastNodeToMove;
        }
        lastNodeToMove.getNode()->next = firstAfterPush;

        if(firstAfterPush == nullptr)
        {
            _back = otherBegin.getNode();
        }

        otherBegin.getNode()->next = otherEnd.getNode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll get linker errors with current file management.

Comment: @Incomputable thanks, so I guess I should have left the implementation in the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments (on top of the obvious file management issue mentioned in the comments):

1. I would switch to `std::unique_ptr<>` instead of raw pointers and `new`/`delete`.
2. I'm not sure I see the purpose of `ForwardList_NodeBase`. Why not just have a pointer to `ForwardList_Node` as the head? You could also get rid of all these nasty `static_cast<>` if you did that.
3. Since you have a `push_back()`, I would have added a `pop_back()` for API consistency, even if it would be slow.
4. You have a bunch of `_beforeBegin.next == nullptr` in the code, yet you use `empty()` in a few places. Be consistent! (`empty()` is much better)
5. Avoid putting multiple statements on the same line (see `T& front()`), it makes debugging a pain. It also makes your code lines too long.
6. I would be in favor of nulling out `_back` when the list becomes empty, even if you have an invariant protecting it. Ask yourself: "Why is it initialized to null at construction?". Keeping dangling pointers around is never good.
7. `ForwardList_Node` and `ForwardListIterator` should be in a sub-namespace to avoid poluting the user-facing one. It's also nice for people who use IDEs with code completion.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.
2. Was thinking of using just ForwardList_Node as the head, but since it is singly-likned list I wanted to have before_head node for methods like splice_after since it takes preceding iterator to the node that will be moved.